# Funcion Click dinámica dentro de For - JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero hacer la función click dinámica para no repetir código, pero no me funciona de esta manera.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 11 ; i++) {
    $('#toggler_'+i).click(function () {
        $('#container-serv_'+i).slideToggle(300, function () {
        });
    });         }
```

Por otro lado si hago lo mismo a nivel individual si que me funciona, alguien sabría decirme cual es la diferencia?

```
$('#toggler_0').click(function () {
        $('#container-serv_0').slideToggle(300, function () {
        });
    });
```

Comment: Y no sería mejor usar una clase?

Comment: De ese modo cuando pulses puedes usar $(this) y recoger la id o el atributo que tú quieras del elemento, o añadir lo que quieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tambien puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
$("[id^='toggler_']").on('click', function() {
    var list = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var i = list[1];
    $('#container-serv_'+i).slideToggle(300, function () {

    });
});
```

esto añadiria la funcion al evento click de todos los elementos cuyo id empiece por 'toggler_'. Dentro estoy cogiendo el id desde el valor del atributo del elemento this, para que lo utilices en el container-serv_  (ya que no sabemos como es tu html, esto quizas se podria simplificar).

Ademas, te quitarias el for...

Answer (score 0):

Al final he añadido un parametro data-num y lo recojo con el this, el código queda así.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 11 ; i++) {
    $('#toggler_'+i).click(function () {
        var num = $(this).data("num");
        $('#container-serv_'+num).slideToggle(300, function () {
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Para mi gusto es una mala practica.. pero si solucioaste, puedes poner tu propia respuesta como la correcta. saludos.

Comment: Tiene razón @Franklin'jGil'z lo que haces es llenar tu código de funciones innecesarias, usando clases es mucho mejor y más práctico!